# WPF.NET 4.0 application is failing on Windows 8 and requires admin account to run

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8

I have a working WPF.NET 4.0 application which is running absolutely fine on all the machines like Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2 etc. But when I tried to run this with a **non-admin** account then the same application on **Windows 8** is failing with **System.Unauthorizedaccessexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll**. On Windows, this  application is working fine with administrator account.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Any chance you can get it debugged on a windows 8 machine and give us further information? If you dont give us the complete source code, we absolutly can't reproduce your problem this question might be closed in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, Serv. The  source code is huge, its a big Enterprise application and currently deployed all across the globe. Sharing the code is not possible for EULA reasons...looks like this is going to close. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I wasn't asking for it - was more of a rhetorical nitbit.

Comment: I understand Serv :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could look into manifest, if requestedExecutionLevel is set to requestAdministrator...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: Thanks Nejc...my application doesn't have a manifest. I am creating that right now.

Comment: im not sure this is your problem because you cant provide source code, but this could be it...

Comment: I have created a new installer and in my environment its working fine...had shared with the client to test on his machine. The most important thing was that I never have had this issue on any of my machines whether its Windows 7 or 8...I am just thinking maybe some group policy has been applied in client network...

Comment: if it works fine in your environment, and not on your client's it could be that, of course...